# What regular expression would strip out all attributes from a BR tag?

Tags: c#, regex

What C# regular expression would replace all of these:

```
<BR style=color:#93c47d>
<BR style=color:#fefefe>
<BR style="color:#93c47d">
<BR style="color:#93c47d ...">
<BR>
<BR/>
<br style=color:#93c47d>
<br style=color:#fefefe>
<br style="color:#93c47d">
<br style="color:#93c47d ...">
<br>
<br/>
```

with:

```
<br/>
```

basically "remove all attributes from any BR element and lowercase it".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @thecoop: That is only relevant for actually parsing HTML, which this question does not require. In this case, the only thing that could break the regex is if there were a ">" inside an attribute, which I believe is invalid anyway.

Comment: Who is the man who thought of that HTML? Can't imagine a use case.

Comment: @Dykam believe it or not, this is HTML that is generated from published google docs, along with FONT tags

Comment: yes, I think google docs must have a specification that their HTML output be compatible with Mosaic 1.0, reminds me of the HTML back in 1993 i.e. FONT tag, no attribute quotes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "<br[^>]*>", "<br/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Or without the `IgnoreCase`:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "<[Bb][Rr][^>]*>", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never had any attributes after style, I would bet something like

```
class Program
{
  const string SOURCE = @"<BR style=color:#93c47d>
<BR style=color:#fefefe>
<BR style=""color:#93c47d"">
<BR style='color:#93c47d'>
<BR>
<BR/>
<br style=color:#93c47d>
<br style=color:#fefefe>
<br style=""color:#93c47d"">
<br style='color:#93c47d'>
<br>
<br/>";

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    const string EXPRESSION = @"(style=[^""'][^>]*)|(style=""[^""]*"")|(style='[^']*')";

    var regex = new Regex(EXPRESSION);

    Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(SOURCE, string.Empty));
  }
}
```

You might be better off with a programmatic solution if there are attributes written into a tag after the style attribute.